# Laravel 4.x Paginate Array

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

For simplicities sake, I have an array, $matches, containing my results in my controller. Normally, I would return a view, passing that array along.

```
return View::make('results', compact('matches'));
```

However, I want to paginate these results in the view.

```
@foreach ($matches as $match)
   ...
@endforeach
// Paginate matches here!
```

It seems like Laravel's built in pagination won't work for arrays. I can't find any resource that shows me how to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up using the following code. You have to pass the items per page manually. `$matches` is the array of data being passed to the paginator.

```
$perPage = 2;
$currentPage = Input::get('page') - 1;
$pagedData = array_slice($matches, $currentPage * $perPage, $perPage);
$matches = Paginator::make($pagedData, count($matches), $perPage);
```

Comment: Withouth a default value for `Input::get('page')` the paginator doesn't work correcly if no query parameter is given. You should change it to `Input::get('page', 1)`

Comment: this is a lifesaver! Paginator itself should slice the $items why do we have to do it in our own..

Answer (score 1):

You can create paginators manually and they work with arrays:

```
$paginator = Paginator::make($items, $totalItems, $perPage);
```

Check the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/pagination

Comment: So what I found is that you have to slice the array yourself before sending it to Paginator::make.

This properly returns the right number of results. However, the pagination links are not functioning. When I click on page 2, I get a page not found error. Is there a custom route I need to write for pagination pages?

Comment: Please remember that when creating a manual paginator, one should slice the array manually as well. They omit this from their docs from 4.x to 5.0, and finally added it on the 5.1 docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually paginate this is the best answer. This is usefull when your query contain distinct().

```
$matches = DB::table('...')->where('...')->distict()->get();    
$perPage = 2;
$currentPage = Input::get('page', 1) - 1;
$pagedData = array_slice($matches, $currentPage * $perPage, $perPage);
$matches = Paginator::make($pagedData, count($matches), $perPage);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much.... :) It works great for me..But :( the links din't works for me..Could you please help me..

Comment: Can you tell me more about how you display links on page?

Comment: I found it :) by using `$query1->setPath('function_name');`... Thanks for your reply.. :)

Comment: @SuganyaRajasekar could you please elaborate your answer